# How to ensure that the source database cannot be modified when using the DMA's migrate option?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-migration-assistant

I am performing a database migration (onprem sql 2016 to onprem sql 2019) using the DMA tool.

The tool only supports one time migration in the above scenario. It does not support an ongoing continuous migration.

How to ensure that the source database cannot be modified during the migration?

Answer (score 2):

you could adopt different strategies like:

- close applications (usually difficult)
- close firewall (usually difficult and it close connection to all databases)
- set database in single user mode (you have to be carefull)
- disable application logins (you have to close them all)
- set database in read-only mode (my favorite)

Comment: Suppose I use the last option (set database in read-only mode),  then post migration I need to change it to read write mode - what is the technical syntax for read-only and read-write mode ?

Comment: do you know how to use a search engine? ^__^

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/04/16/sql-server-making-database-to-read-only-changing-database-to-readwrite/